# Do certain operations after another thread has completed execution

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `threadA` which runs `threadB`. After `threadB` has completed its run method, I want `threadA` to perform some actions. Of course, I can do something like this in code of `threadA`:

```
Thread threadB = new Thread(myRunnable);
threadB.run();
threadB.join();
doStuff();
```

But this will make `threadA` to wait until `threadB` has completed execution. I don't want this to happen.

I want `threadA` to keep running normally when `threadB` is running, and as soon as `threadB` terminates, `doStuff()` is called. Something like this:

```
//some code

Thread threadB = new Thread(myRunnable);
// block for b
{
    threadB.run();
    threadB.join();
    doStuff();
}

//some more code which should run while "block for b" is running
```

Comment: Then, uhm, why not make thread B handle the extra stuff? Also, don't use Thread directly, use ExecutorServices

Comment: Currently I am asking threadB to do it, but I want it to be removed from there because its something that's concerned with threadA

Comment: If `doStuff();` has something which is dependent on state of threadA and you want to run threadA while threadB is in progress and then call `doStuff();` once threadB is finished then as per best of my knowledge to ensure that threadA is not halted no matter how long threadB takes is by calling `doStuff();` in the end of threadA and holding threadA using `threadB.isAlive()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey 's answer is the correct one.  Why do you care which thread does the work?  If your `doStuff()` uses or modifies state that only thread A can see, why not make that state visible to thread B?  With the right encapsulation, making the state visible to _one method_ that is called from thread B does not have to mean making the state visible everywhere in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> threadB is running, and as soon as threadB terminates, doStuff() is called.

A simpler solution is for ThreadB to do stuff after it has finished running.

```
Thread threadB = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
           myRunnable.run();
        } finally {
           doStuff();
        }
    }
});
```

This way no other thread needs to be involved.

Comment: That's an elegant solution and even @fge has recommended but seems like OP has something in `doStuff()` which depends on state of threadA. He has said - *Currently I am asking threadB to do it, but I want it to be removed from there because its something that's concerned with threadA*

Comment: @hagrawal yes that is what the issue can be, but I'll try to find a workaround

Comment: This thing worked well. I just changed the `new Runnable()` part to `new MyRunnable()` & `myRunnable.run()` to `super.run()` and works well. Anonymous classes are always to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

In `threadA`, poll `threadB.isAlive()`, and if `threadB` is not running anymore, do the stuff you want to do:

```
threadB.start();
while (...) {
    ...
    if (!threadB.isAlive()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```